# Select One option At a time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox, typescript-typings

I am using react-native element for checkbox there 4 option for payment but unable to set state for check box
kindly click on link to view code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K2yhte4vr2U9H78jUHxMyv3MNimcp-sq/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Select Why you are using checkbox? If you want to Select One option At a time use Radiobutton plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-radio-button

Add your payment options in arrays and render it, when you select one option it will automatically setState and selected.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but I cant use additional package for that task , I have to manage by using checkbox please help how i do using conditions